# How to update the value of array in Yii session

Tags: php, arrays, session, multidimensional-array, yii

I am using "ajaxSubmitButton" to send some values of 3 fields: registrant, product id and quantity to controller (controller name: actionCart). After submitting the button I receive those values in session array what I did successfully. At this point, if I submit same product id but different quantity, I want to update the quantity key with new value. I have done this by php global $_SESSION but can't using Yii session variable.

```
public function actionCart()
{

    if(isset($_POST["Order"])){
        $item = $_POST["Order"];
        $registration_id = $item["registration_id"];
        $this->productId = $item["item"];
        $quantity = $item["quantity"];
        $quantity = $item["quantity"]=='' ? 1 : $item["quantity"];

        $productInfo = Products::model()->findByPk(array('id'=>$this->productId));
        $totalPrice = $productInfo->price * $quantity;

        $newItem = array("product_id" => $this->productId , "product_name" => $productInfo->name, "quantity" => $quantity,"price" => $productInfo->price,"totalPrice" => $totalPrice);

        $session = Yii::app()->session;
        $cartArray = $session['cart'];

        $searchArrResult = $this->searchSubArray($session['cart'],'product_id',$this->productId);
        if (!empty($searchArrResult)) {
            /***** this works *****/
            foreach ( $_SESSION['cart'] as $key=>$cart ) {
                if ( $cart["product_id"] == $this->productId ) {
                    $_SESSION['cart'][$key]['quantity']=$quantity;
                    $_SESSION['cart'][$key]['totalPrice']=$totalPrice;
                }
            }
            /***** following commented code does not work *****
             *
             foreach($session['cart'] as $key=>$cart){
                if ($cart["product_id"] == $this->productId){
                    $session['cart'][$key]['quantity'] == $quantity;
                    $session['cart'][$key]['totalPrice'] == $totalPrice;
                }
            }*/

        }
        else {
            $cartArray[] = $newItem;
            $session['cart'] = $cartArray;
        }

        print_r($session['cart']);
        //unset(Yii::app()->session['cart']);

    }

}
```

In the above code I marked by commenting where I want to update session values. Please help me someone if it is possible do in yii.

Comment: Maybe You should first try [Google](https://www.google.com/#q=yii+update+session)?

Comment: I tried in google but did not find any solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

> ```
> $carts = $session['cart'];
> foreach($carts as $key=>&$cart){
>     if ($cart["product_id"] == $this->productId){
>          $cart['quantity'] == $quantity;
>          $cart['totalPrice'] == $totalPrice;
>     }
> }
> $session['cart'] = $carts;
> ```

`Yii::app()->session` return object of `CHttpSession`, not reference to $_SESSION.

`$carts = $session['cart']` equals operation `$carts = $session->get('cart');` (by means magic method __get in CHttpSession) and `$session['cart'] = $carts;` equals to `$session->set('cart', $carts);` (by __set)

That's why you can't setting by `$session['cart'][$key]['quantity'] = $quantity;`

**UPDATED** full solution (I change logic of saving products - $key = product_id)

> ```
> public function actionCart()
> {
>     if(isset($_POST["Order"])){
>         $item = $_POST["Order"];
>         $registration_id = $item["registration_id"];
>         $this->productId = $item["item"];
>         $quantity = empty(intval($item["quantity"])) ? 1 : intval($item["quantity"]);
>         $productInfo = Products::model()->findByPk(array('id'=>$this->productId));.
>         if(empty($productInfo))
>              return false; // or other action
>         $newItem = array(
>              "product_id" => $this->productId , 
>              "product_name" => $productInfo->name, 
>              "quantity" => $quantity,
>              "price" => $productInfo->price,
>              "totalPrice" => ($productInfo->price * $quantity)
>         );
>         $cartArray = Yii::app()->session['cart'];
>         $cartArray[$this->productId] = $newItem;
>         Yii::app()->session['cart'] = $cartArray;
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: thanks to good explanation. But it doesn't work. So, I tried to change a line `$session['cart'] = $carts;` to `$session['cart'] = $cart;` but it change the array format i.e. `Array ( [product_id] => 5 [product_name] => Denim [quantity] => 5 [price] => 500 [totalPrice] => 2500 [0] => Array ( [product_id] => 5 [product_name] => Denim [quantity] => 5 [price] => 500 [totalPrice] => 2500 ) ) `

Comment: No, you must leave `$session['cart'] = $carts;`, because in the foreach i'm working exactly with $key product and change it info by reference (look at `&$cart`, it means if I do `$cart['quantity'] == $quantity` I change `$carts[$key]['quantity']`, I make some optimisation your code)

Comment: It works if I select single product. Once I select multiple product, following product values are being overlapped by previous product's value. You have answered on one of my another post what is related to it. In this post I have already given whole controller code. If I did nay wrong, could you please let me know the issue to reach at the final solution.

Comment: Look at my full solution, please

Comment: Your updated code works nicely. It's really a cool solution. Many many thanks to have patience to cooperate me.